# download a local txt file from express in react

Tags: node.js, json, reactjs, express, axios

i have tried to download a file but downloaded file doesnt have orginal value instead it has

> {"type":"Buffer","data":[97,115,100,102,108,107,106,104,97,115,100,102,108,107,106,104,97,115,100,102,108,107,106,104,97,115,100,102,108,107,106,104]}

my serverside code is

```
router.post('/getAttachmentFile',(request,response) => {
    fs.readFile('test.txt', function (err,data){
        response.contentType("application/txt");
        console.log("data value",data)
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        }
        else if(data){
            response.json(data);
        }
    });
```

})

and my client side code is

```
fileAxios.post('/getAttachmentFile').then(
  response => {
    console.log(response,response.blob,{
      type: "application/txt"
    });
    const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data]));
    const link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.setAttribute('download', 'sample.txt'); //or any other extension
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  }
).catch(err => {console.log(err)})
```

}

where fileAxios is

```
const fileAxios = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:5000/api",
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'text/plain',
        'Content-Disposition': "attachment;filename=sample.txt"
    },
    responseType: "blob"
});
```

[image: this was the file that was downloaded]

this was the file that was downloaded

Answer (score 0):

fs.readFile() pass through nodejs Buffer object as a 2nd argument. Buffer is not
text but binary data. Did you tried to data.toString('what-ever-your-text-file-encode')?

PS.
I recommend you to change the file handling part from fs.readFile to fs Stream API for piping to response. To do so, you can stream the binary data for the client.

check this out
https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html

```js
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const fs = require('fs')

router.get('/:filename', async (req, res, next) => {
        fs
        .createReadStream(`./${req.params.filename}`)
        .pipe(res)
        .on('error', (err) => {
             console.log('Error in read stream...')
         })

        res.on('error', (err) => {
            console.log('Error in write stream...')
        })
})

module.exports = router`
```

Assume that your file is in the root directory of npm, this router will work fine for the server.

change the prefix `./` if directory is not root, I recomment the `path.join` for doing so.

Comment: what if the file is pdf or image or xls

Comment: It seems to you need to read file as a binary for those file types. Set the mimetype for the file with proper extension(pdf for pdf, xls for xls) and pipe it from HTTP. Unless you need to open the file in browser, now the problem is on the client local PC not for the server.

Comment: can you show a sample code for streaming the file to response so that file can be downloaded

Comment: sorry for massing up with comment, I thought markdown works in comment. I add server-side code in the answer.

Comment: I write some code but that kind of doing so looks not safe. In production, you'd better scope the directory to downloading file. unless, server file can be exposed by crackers.